# The requested address is not valid in its context

Tags: python, сервер, amazon-web-services

Пытаюсь запустить сервер python на дедике от Амазона (aws dedicated server). Они предоставляют статический ip для подключения.

```
   import socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind(("тут айпи", 8888))
result = sock.recv(1024)
print("message ", result.decode("utf-8"))
sock.close()
```

Мне выдает ошибку: [WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context

Перелазил всё, ничего не нашёл. Фаервол отключил и все другие исключения тоже

Comment: Скорее всего "тут айпи" не соответствует ни одному сетевому интерфейсу который есть у данного сервера.

Comment: @GrAnd это Вы к тому, что я не указал настоящий ip в теме? Если нет, то не могли бы подсказать, как проверить вашу догадку

Comment: Это я к тому, что эта ошибка обычно возникает тогда, когда IP, что вы реально указали, у машинки отсутствует. Вы проверяли, у неё есть на сетевом интерфейсе указанный вами IP?